# Переход по страницам без перезагрузки

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте, решил сделать на сайте переход по страницам без перезагрузки, сделал через `history.replaceState(null, null, null);`.

Так вот, в чем сама проблема, я как понял, это визуально все делается, а у меня на страницах стоит вывод по `$_GET[id]`, а выдает он тот id, который был на прошлой странице. То есть было: **test.ru/?id=1**, url сам стал **test.ru/?id=2**, но а на странице вывожу `echo $_GET[id];`, он выдает **1**.

Так как мне сделать, чтобы он менялся не только визуально, но при этом и без перезагрузки? Может можно как то заменить этот get параметр после визуального изменения url?

Comment: по поводу перехода по страницам без перезагрузки - почитайте про SPA (react, vue, angular). На чистом JS писать заново смысла нет, уже все изобретено

Comment: @Alexxosipov Это конечно все хорошо, но на сайте много страниц и переписывать что-то не охота уже... Поэтому ищу вариант как бы всё-таки решить эту проблему более проще и быстрее

Comment: Ох...если сайт будет потом переделываться (а этого не избежать), то масштабируемость кода, который предполагается у вас, будет очень низкой. Это очень большой костыль

Comment: @Aue без переписывания хрен вы это сделаете нормально, говорю как сам делавший это неоднократно

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду говоря "стоит вывод по $_GET[id]"? Это же не php в браузере

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko на страницах есть sql запросы в которых вывод по $_GET[id]

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю, ведь  $_GET[id] это из php

Comment: Возможно вам поможет этот пример https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Example Кстати pushState создаёт новую запись в истории, а replaceState не создаёт. Нужно каким-то образом следить за событиями истории и действовать по ситуации. В общем геморрой ещё тот

Comment: в общем я понял вашу проблему и ответил нижу

Comment: `History API` работает только с историей браузера и адресной-строкой, запрос не посылается (от того и скорость). Для более правильного подхода нужно использовать `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score -1):

Приветствую

После того, как вы изменили состояние history (кстати требуется в данной задаче использовать pushState, а не replaceState), нужно самостоятельно произвести требуемые операции по обновлению страницы (отправить запросы, обновить dom и т.д.).

Операции стоит производить в обработчике события popstate

> A popstate event is dispatched to the window each time the active
>   history entry changes between two history entries for the same
>   document. If the activated history entry was created by a call to
>   history.pushState(), or was affected by a call to
>   history.replaceState(), the popstate event's state property contains a
>   copy of the history entry's state object

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(e) {
  // Здесь обновляем страницу
});
```

Доп материалы по теме:
https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate